# Get Database ID in a listView using Array adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I just want to know how to get the database ID(Recipe ID) from the listView using setOnItemClickListener?

Here is my listRecipeAdapter extending ArrayAdapater...

```
public class ListRecipeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

List list = new ArrayList();

public ListRecipeAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}
static class LayoutHandler {
    TextView RECIPENAME, RECIPECONTRIBUTOR, RECIPEPREPTIME, RECIPECOOKTIME;
}

@Override
public void add(Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe_view_layout, parent, false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.RECIPENAME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.recipe_name);
        layoutHandler.RECIPEPREPTIME = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.recipe_preptime);
        layoutHandler.RECIPECOOKTIME = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.recipe_cooktime);
        layoutHandler.RECIPECONTRIBUTOR = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.recipe_contributor);
        row.setTag(layoutHandler);
    } else {
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();
    }
    Recipe recipe = (Recipe) this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.RECIPENAME.setText(recipe.getRecipeName());
    layoutHandler.RECIPEPREPTIME.setText(recipe.getRecipePreparationTime());
    layoutHandler.RECIPECOOKTIME.setText(recipe.getRecipeCookTime());
    layoutHandler.RECIPECONTRIBUTOR.setText(recipe.getRecipeContributor());
    return row;
}}
```

And here's my View Activity...

```
listRecipeAdapter = new ListRecipeAdapter(getApplicationContext(),  R.layout.recipe_view_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(listRecipeAdapter);
grabRecipeSQLOperations = new      GrabRecipeSQLOperations(getApplicationContext());

sqLiteDatabase = grabRecipeSQLOperations.getReadableDatabase();

    String recipeName, recipeContributor, recipePrepTime, recipeCookTime;
    int recipeID;
    cursor = grabRecipeSQLOperations.getRecipeRecords(sqLiteDatabase, storeTag);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            recipeID = cursor.getInt(0);
            recipeName = cursor.getString(1);
            recipeContributor = cursor.getString(2);
            recipeCookTime = cursor.getString(3);
            recipePrepTime = cursor.getString(4);
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe(recipeID,recipeName, recipePrepTime, recipeCookTime, recipeContributor);
            recipe.recipeView(recipeID,recipeName, recipePrepTime, recipeCookTime, recipeContributor);
            listRecipeAdapter.add(recipe);
           //how to see IDs
            String list = Integer.toString(recipe.getRecipeId());
            Log.e("IDS:", list);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Clicked item id", String.valueOf(id));
        }
    });
```

Once the listener is clicked, it will log the database id BUT apparently only
the ListView's position is logged in Logcat.

Comment: i read that the long id gets the database id of the clicked listview row

Comment: It's a common error to believe that the item positions correspond to the ids in a database table

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) I already solved it by the way

Comment: String recId = String.valueOf(((Recipe)       parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getRecipeId());